# Create one printer entry for multiple printers of the same model

Tags: windows, windows-xp, drivers, printer

When I switch between two or more different HP Laserjet P1606dn 
machines using the same computer, the computer automatically 
installs a new instance of that printer (copy 1, copy 2, etc).  I 
would like to keep the one printer entry in windows when I switch 
different HP machines as this windows computer will be moving 
between over ten different stations throughout the day that all 
have an HP Laserjet P1606dn on them.  Having a copy of the printer 
for each station becomes very cluttered and unprofessional.
Does anyone know if there is a way to do this?

From what I've found so far, 
Each USB device has a unique serial ID tag, so Windows will know if it's been 
used/installed before.
It's also worth noting that the HP Laserjet P1606dn has the Smart Install feature and loads itself as a drivers CD when connected.  This isn't an issue as I've disabled autoplay, but I thought I should mention it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a login script that deleted the existing printer each time someone logs on and then refreshes hardware to force a printer reinstall?

Comment: Excellent. If you would mark that as the answer then please, and best of luck.